# SQL persistence service

Tags: sql-server, persistence

I am trying to run the code sample from Workflow Foundation which uses persistence service's functionality. In the code I've observed:

```
Initial Catalog=SqlPersistenceService;Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

When I run the code I am getting an exception. How do I enable persistence services on my SQLEXPRESS server?

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

See `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Workflow Foundation\SQL\EN`. These are the scripts that enable `SqlWorkflowPersistenceService`.

You'll need `SqlPersistenceService_Schema.sql` and `SqlPersistenceService_Logic.sql`. First one defines the structure of database and tables and second one defines stored procedures.

Comment: @Anton: is it possible to create the database and tables through VS2008?  I have created the database, but am not sure which type is ideal.  Also, I have tried to paste the SQL text from the file into the Query window in VS2008, but execution results in an error.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246968/managing-workflow-lifecycle-without-a-persistence-service/2283117#2283117